# How to determine if address is word aligned

Tags: memory-alignment

Can you tell by looking at them which of these addresses is *word aligned*?

0x000AE430
0X00014432
0X000B0737
0X0E0D8844

Comment: Is this homework? What's your machine's word size? Yes, I can.

Comment: divisible by machine word size?

Comment: For a word size of N the address needs to be a multiple of N. *Hint*: for most common values of N you just need to look at the last digit of the address.

Comment: After almost 5 years, isn't it time to accept the answer and respectfully bow to vhallac?

Answer (score 17):

The short answer is, yes. But you have to define the number of bytes per word. Some architectures call two bytes a word, and four bytes a double word. In any case, you simply mentally calculate `addr%word_size` or `addr&(word_size - 1)`, and see if it is zero. When the address is hexadecimal, it is trivial: just look at the rightmost digit, and see if it is divisible by word size.

For a word size of 4 bytes, second and third addresses of your examples are unaligned. Second has 2 and third one has a 7, neither of which are divisible by 4. For a word size of 2 bytes, only third address is unaligned.